# Python- How to pass Feedparser object to a celery task?

Tags: python, celery, feedparser, jsonserializer

I've using `feedparser` module to parse the RSS feeds. I need to pass the feedparser object to a celery task.

Upon trying to pass the object, I receive an error  saying `time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=8, tm_min=19, tm_sec=11, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=43, tm_isdst=0) is not JSON serializable`

How do I pass the feedparser object to a celery task?

Here is my code:-

```
rss_content = feedparser.parse(rss_link)
content_entries = rss_content['entries']
for content in content_entries:
    parse_link.apply_async(args=[content, link, json_id, news_category], queue= news_source) #celery task
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your custom encoder and decoder that will basically convert your `time.time_struct` object into something serializable (a dict), and then register them in the kombu serializer registry as described in the [docs](http://kombu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/serialization.html#serialization), in order to let celery use your new serializer in its task.

```
import json
import time
import types
import datetime

class FeedContentEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):   
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, time_struct):
            epoch = int(time.mktime(time_struct))
            return {'__type__': '__time__', 'time': epoch}
        else:
            return json.FeedContentEncoder.default(self, obj)

def decode_feed_content(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, types.DictionaryType) and '__type__' in obj:
        if obj['__type__'] == '__time__':
            return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(obj['time']).timetuple()
    return obj
```

You need to notify kombu about your new serialization by registering them into the serializer registry.

```
from kombu.serialization import register

def feed_content_json_dumps(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj, cls=FeedContentEncoder)

def feed_content_json_loads(obj):
    return json.loads(obj, object_hook=decode_feed_content)

register('feedcontentjson', 
         feed_content_json_dumps, 
         feed_content_json_loads, 
         content_type='application/x-feedcontent-json', 
         content_encoding='utf-8')
```

Finally, you should tell celery to use the new serializer for serializing the task just like the [celery docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-accept-content); you should call your task with the `serializer` parameter.

```
parse_link.apply_async(args=[content, link, json_id, news_category], queue= news_source, serializer='feedcontentjson')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I made a `serializer.py` file in the same directory where `celeryconfig.py`  was placed.  Where do I register my new serialization?In which file? and how the celery will get to know about my new serialization? How to connect these files?

Comment: I solved it via pickling the Feedparser object. Thanks anyways. :)